# Sair do modal após retorno do resultado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-3

Após deletar e retornar para o index...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Remove(id);
        _unitOfWork.Salva();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

O meu modal não sai..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cód btnDelete

```
    <div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
        <input id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="EXCLUIR" />
    </div>
```

Como faço para que ele saia automaticamente?

Comment: $('.moda-footer').close() ?

Comment: Então, tinha tentado fazer assim, no evento click do botão mas dependendo do atributo que eu coloco ele não sai ou o model nem aparece.

Comment: Deu certo assim..
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Eu coloquei esse script acima mas ai não atualizava minha view automaticamente, ai eu só alterei no controller o 
return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
Por
return Json(new { success = true });
E deu certo, não precisei do script, vlw..

Comment: $( this ).dialog( "close" );  ou algo assim. Eu tenho um código que faz isso e dá certo